# How to toggle class of a div element by clicking on button in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to toggleclass name of one element by clicking on another element. Both elements are in separate component files. I don't know how to get the state of an element and pass it to another element. Please help me solving the problem.

**file1.js**

```
<Button onClick={this.toggleFunction}>Button</Button>
```

**file2.js**

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

I want to toggle class **active** on **wrapper div** when the button is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far? Are the components siblings, or are they parent/child?

Comment: The components are parent/child

Comment: So you want to toggle a class in the parent when a button in the child is clicked?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/m4py2y97zp

Comment: button is in one file.js and the wrapper div is in another file2.js. So i want to toggle class on wrapper div from button click.

Comment: Yes, but it's an important distinction if you want to toggle a class in the child by clicking a button in the parent, or if you want to toggle a class in the parent by clicking a button in the child.

Comment: @SanjayA your toggle function and applying element both are on same file. I want to toggle class from one file to another file.

Comment: @Tholle I want to change class of a parent wrapper by clicking button in the child.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/m4py2y97zp   -> Using Parent /Child Relation

Comment: @SanjayA your code worked thanks

Answer (score 3):

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addActiveClass= this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            active: false,
        };
    }
    toggleClass() {
        const currentState = this.state.active;
        this.setState({ active: !currentState });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div 
                className={this.state.active ? 'your_className': null} 
                onClick={this.toggleClass} 
            >
                <p>{this.props.text}</p>
            </div>
        )
  }
}
```

Comment: The code runs on the same file. I want to apply changes from 1 file to another. My button is in header.js and I want to apply change in base.js file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Parent Component 
        import React from "react";
        import ButtonComponent from "./buttonComponent";
        import "./demo.css";

        //Parent  Component
        class Demo extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              active: false
            };
          }

          updateValue = value => {
            this.setState({
              active: value
            });
          };
          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <ButtonComponent updateParent={this.updateValue} />
                <div
                  className={
                    this.state.active ? "dropdownbutton1" : "dropdownbutton1Active"
                  }
                >
                  <label>First</label>
                  <br />
                  <select>
                    <option value="yes">yes</option>
                    <option value="no">no</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default Demo;
Child Component 

        import React from "react";
        import ToggleButton from "react-toggle-button";
        import "./demo.css";

        class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              active: false,
              defaultValue: 1
            };
          }

          togglebutton = () => {
            this.props.updateParent(this.state.active);
            this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
            if (this.state.active) {
              this.setState({ defaultValue: 1 });
            } else {
              this.setState({ defaultValue: -1 });
            }
          };
          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <div className="ToggleButton">
                  <ToggleButton onClick={this.togglebutton} value={this.state.active} />
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default ButtonComponent;
```

Link :https://codesandbox.io/s/m4py2y97zp

Comment: Please don't delete this link.

Comment: Hello, Can you add the normal button instead of switch button ?

Comment: Changing <ToogleButton  onClick={this.togglebutton} value={this.state.active} />   to    <button onClick={this.togglebutton} value={this.state.active} >Click Me</button>
Should work

Comment: I am getting below error Unexpected token (16:18)

  14 |       }
  15 | 
> 16 |       updateValue = value => {
     |                   ^
  17 |         this.setState({
  18 |           active: value
  19 |         });

errors @ client:167
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:883
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:881
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2957

Comment: can you please help me out

Comment: Css not loaded are you seeking to highlight search bar on click...https://codesandbox.io/s/m51o0yvo3y